# How to execute function, after payment was received (Sofort)?

Tags: node.js, integration, payment-gateway

I'm trying to integrate sofort as a payment option into my node js application, and so far everything works. The only problem, that I have is, that I don't know how to execute a function after I received the payment. Right now i only get redirected to sofort, transfer my money and then get redirected to the success URL but I dont how to give the Server a sign, that the payment was received.
I thought I could use the notification URL as a way to communicate with the server but it doesn't send a GET or a POST request, and therefore I dont't really know what it actually does

Here is my code so far:

```
router.get('/sofort', function(req, res, next) {
'use strict';
var util = require('util');
var Sofort = new (require('node-sofort'))({
    configKey : '181556:493374:5c3627c5d50e1f77ee0f5824abb46084'
});

try {
    Sofort.createPayment(101.00, 'EUR', ['Demo1'], {
        user_variables: ['variable1','variable2','variable3'],
        success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        success_link_redirect: true,
        notification_urls: 'http://localhost:3000/testo'}, function (err, 
data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.payment_url);
        res.redirect(data.payment_url)
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
)}
```

If you have anything in mind, that could help just say it

Comment: you need to corectly use your success_url, `success_url - String (255)

Success link, overwrites the default value from the project settings. Is called when your customer successfully executed SOFORT Banking and the transfer has been listed in the customer's online banking. If the transaction ID of SOFORT Banking should be used as part of the URL, the parameter '-TRANSACTION-' can be inserted in the URL String.

    If no success link is defined in the project settings this parameter becomes mandatory

{ success_url: 'https://www.example.com/sofort/success' }`

Comment: you need create a correct url on your node server, to be able to redirect to and receive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the success_url to

```
success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/sofort/success/-TRANSACTION-'
```

and then create a route (post or get I dont know)

```
router.post('/sofort/success/:transaction', function(req, res) {
    var transactionId = req.body.transaction;

    console.log('transaction succesful for id ' + transactionId);    

    res.end();
});
```

Comment: thanks that worked :) even though the transactionId was undefined :/

Comment: I never used this library, just worked based of the docs.  Maybe you need to check the formatting and/or placement of the TRANSACTION parameter.  The doc is quite comprehensive

Comment: just check in your debugger/network tab if any transaction id is sent.  if yes, you can find out the name of the parameter you need to put in your route.   maybe like `:TRANSACTION` or `:transactionId`

Comment: Okay I just fished the transactionId out of the URL string